# Compare sums ssreflect

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, ssreflect

I am aiming to say that if we have

```
sum(a) = sum(b)
```

then

```
a = b.
```

What would be the suitable tactic to do this, if the goal looks like this:

```
\big[Radd_comoid/0]_(i <- fin_img (A:=U) (B:=R_eqType) X)
   Radd_comoid
     (Pr P F * (i * Pr P (finset (T:=U) (preim X (pred1 i)) :&: F) / Pr P F))
     (Pr P (~: F) *
      (i * Pr P (finset (T:=U) (preim X (pred1 i)) :&: ~: F) / Pr P (~: F))) =
\sum_(u in U) X u * `p_ X u
```

Editted.
The context contains:

```
X: {RV (P) -> (R)}
F: {set U}
H: 0 < Pr P F
H0: Pr P F < 1
```

The goal after `rewrite /=.` looks like this:

```
\big[Rplus/0]_(i <- fin_img (A:=U) (B:=R_eqType) X)
   (Pr P F * (i * Pr P (finset (T:=U) (preim X (pred1 i)) :&: F) / Pr P F) +
    Pr P (~: F) *
    (i * Pr P (finset (T:=U) (preim X (pred1 i)) :&: ~: F) / Pr P (~: F))) =
\sum_(u in U) X u * `p_ X u
```

Comment: This is not true except for very special cases, example, sum [0;1] = sum [1;0]

Comment: Can you issue a `rewrite /=` on the goal so we get to see it better? By the way, asking for help on the Coq topic without including a Minimal, Reproducible Example it kinda moot.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Adding the information to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If it is true, you probably need to use `sum_parti_finType` on the right hand side and try to identify the general terms of the summation using `eq_bigr`. The general term of the left hand side can be simplified using `mulrC mulfVK` (or something like this) on both sides of the `+`. And then identify a sum of probabilities with the probability of the disjoint union.
Anyway, it's not just "a tactic"...